# Хранение нулевого символа в std::string?

Tags: c++, строки, std

Скажите, пожалуйста, разрешено ли помещать нулевой символ в строку `std::string`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2845774/7485582

Comment: почему нет _ это тоже символ.+

Comment: можно, но люди будут косо смотреть и перешёптываться у тебя за спиной...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запросто. Только надо знать, как сохранить :)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s = "Hello, \0\0\0world"s;
    for(auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
        cout << "code: " << hex << int(*it) <<endl;
}
```

Просто если инициализировать C-строкой, то по нулю обрежется... - см. https://ideone.com/Ted3sG

Comment: Не забыть  `using namespace std::string_literals;`